# How to check to make sure user entry matches a certain beginning character

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that uses a scanner to get user entry and check if it begins with y or Y to perform an action. Any other entry will be considered false and perform a different action.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
userInput = scnr.next().charAt(0);
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

This is what I'm thinking at this point, but it's not my full code. I understand that string and char are incompatible, but I'm not sure how else this could be done. I also don't just want to put multiple variations of the entry in the if statement like this

```
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yup"))
```

I hope this question makes sense. I'm new to programming and this website, so I'm sorry if this obvious!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't take the character as a char and compare it? `myChar == 'y' || myChar == 'Y'` works just fine if all you care about is that the first character of the input is 'y' or 'Y'.

Comment: @ChrisGong Thank you! I have been searching for an answer to this for so long, but I completely missed that post for some reason. I ended up using .substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y") and it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

```
userInput = scnr.next();
if (userInput.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {
   //if input start with y or yup : do something
}
else{
  //else : do another thing         
}
```

Comment: Would this also be acceptable? (userInput.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))

Comment: @dlawil2049 this also works , because substring(**begin**,**end**) return string between **begin** and **end**-1

Comment: You need to check whether a String is empty or not Too. Cause if it is  then it will give you an error

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya **scnr.next()**  can't return empty string , but if he use **scnr.nextLine()** this will cause **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**

Answer (score 0):

You also can use regex for your input as:

```
    String str = "Your String";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("y.*|Y.*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(str); // Display the string.
    }
```